# Не знаю как разместить текст внутри Polygon(яндекс карта)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Вообщем сделал я геометрическую фигуру с помощью Polygon(яндекс карта). И мне нужно внутри этой фигуры сделать текст. Но я не понимаю как это можно сделать. Пробовал использовать iconContent, но это не помогло. Вот функция которую я использую.

```
function createStation(coordinates, hintValue, background) {
  stations.push(new ymaps.Polygon([
      // Указываем координаты вершин многоугольника.
      // Координаты вершин внешнего контура.
      coordinates
  ], {
      // Описываем свойства геообъекта.
      // Содержимое балуна.
      iconContent: 0,
      hintContent: hintValue
  }, {
      // Задаем опции геообъекта.
      // Цвет заливки.
      fillColor: background,
      strokeWidth: 2
  }));
}
```

**P.s. Использую map api v2.1.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день. В песочнице JS API Яндекс Карт есть пример https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polylabeler

Comment: Я спросил как можно сделать это с Polygon, в примере я этого не увидел.

Comment: К примеру https://jsfiddle.net/86f2vw07/